# MySQL code to postgres

Tags: mysql, psql

Hello i would like to know how to do something like this in postgres. I know interjoin databases is not supported by postgres. But i believe there is some way.

```
UPDATE lportal.layoutset l, lportal2.layoutset l2 
SET l.themeId = l2.themeId 
WHERE l.layoutSetId = l2.layoutSetId;
```

thanks you guys.

Comment: What are `lportal` and `lportal2`? Schemas? Databases? something else? It doesn't do much good to show the code if you don't show what the object you're referring to are.

Comment: sorry. those are databases.

Answer (score 1):

Cross-database queries are not supported in PostgreSQL. You can hack around that with [dblink](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/dblink.html), but it's really not very nice.

If possible, restructure to use multiple *schemas* within a single *database*.